# Names with Apostrophes in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I am putting together a paper, and an author in the citations has a name with an apostrophe. When I compile the pdf, the apostrophe is dropped, rendering the name from D'Urso to DUrso. How do I force BibTex to respect the apostrophe?

```
@article{HPdura,
    author = "B D’Urso",
    title = "title",
    year = "year",
    journal = "Journal",
    volume = "volume", 
    Pages  = "pages",
}
```

which gives in the .BBL

```
\bibitem{HPdura}
 B.~D’Urso, Title, Journal Volume (year) pages.
```

which gives in the PDF

```
B. DUrso, title, Journal volume (year) pages.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a single quote: `'`, rather than an apostrophe: `’`

Comment: I did (keep in mind there is only one key). It decided to change them on its own, which causes bibtex to fail. How do I make it not change things?

Comment: What is "it"? This sounds like an issue with whatever software you're using to edit your .bib file. A text editor shouldn't change anything, but a wordprocessor might.

Comment: There is one key on a standard keyboard that has a single quote, that is the one next to enter (quote key" '). Your program, be it word processor or text editor, decides whether this counts as single quote or apostrophe. There isn't any way to control this decision, so having functions depend on this distinction is a problem.